# Set a reverse foreignkey relationship in django without saving

Tags: python, django

if you have an instance of a django object, you can set a field and if you don't save it, it goes away.

if you have a foreignkey relationship and you use `set`, `clear`, etc.  the change you made is immediately written to the db.  this makes sense, but is there a way not to do this.  As in to temporarily modify the relationship objects, similar to what you can do for a charfield, etc.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

```
class Foo(model):
  name = charfield()

class Bar(model):
  name = charfield()
  foo = Foreignkey(Foo, related_name="bars", null=True)

bar1 = Bar.objects.create(name="bar1")
bar2 = Bar.objects.create(name="bar2")

foo = Foo.objects.create(id=1, name="dog")
foo.bars.add(bar1)
foo.bars.add(bar2)

foo.name >> "dog"
foo.name = "cat"
foo.name >> "cat"
len(foo.bars.all()) >> 2
foo.bars.clear()
len(foo.bars.all()) >> 0


foo1 = Foo.objects.get(id=1)
foo1.name >> "dog"
len(foo1.bars.all()) >> 0.  ---->>>> i want this to remain 2
```